# How to use filter function to pick out specific dates?

Tags: r, filter, lubridate

I cannot filter my data set for a specific date.

```
padf_12 <- read.table("Paddus_2012_sheet2.csv", head = TRUE, sep=";" )
tibble(padf_12)

padf_12 <- padf_12 %>% 
mutate_at(vars(Block, Treatment), factor) %>% 
mutate("Date"=dmy(Date, tz = "UTC"))
```

I have tried different ways to filter the data e.g.

```
padf_12 <- padf_12 %>%
filter_at(padf_12, vars(Date == "2012-08-14"))
```

and

```
padf_12 <- padf_12 %>%
filter(padf_12, Treatment == "2012-08-14")
```

Due to error codes I have tried to convert my dates to POSIXct

```
padf_12 <- padf_12 %>% 
mutate(as.POSIXct(padf_12$Date, tz="", format="%Y-%m-%d"))
```

My data looks like this:

```
Sample       Date     Time Plot Ch..Vol..L. Plot..old. iButton Treatment Block X2.methylbutyl.acetat X3.hexenyl.acetate
1 31-K1 20120522 2012-05-22 14:01:00   C1          13         K1  2198C9         C     1                  0.00               0.02
2 32-K1 20120613 2012-06-13 10:19:00   C1          13         K1  2198C9         C     1                  0.00               0.00
3 33-K1 20120626 2012-06-26 12:19:00   C1          13         K1   21980         C     1                  0.00               0.00
4 34-K1 20120715 2012-07-15 12:15:00   C1          13         K1  2198CD         C     1                  0.00               0.02
5 35-K1 20120814 2012-08-14            C1          13         K1                 C     1                  0.00               2.34
6 36-K2 20120522 2012-05-22 15:12:00   C2          13         K2  2198C9         C     2                  0.01               0.04
```

And here's a link to the full data set:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/m4qfrdagqxvdxnh/Filtering%20problem.R?dl=0

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What about using `subset`? something like `subset(padf_12, date == "2012-08-14")`

Comment: Not sure if this causes the problem, but if you use the pipe operator %>% you do not need to specifiy the .data object of the following function. So instead of `padf_12 <- padf_12 %>% filter(padf_12, Treatment == "2012-08-14")`,`padf_12 <- padf_12 %>% filter(Treatment == "2012-08-14")` should be enough.

Comment: thank you very much both of you. Removing data object in the function did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the data object in the function as suggested by TinglTanglBob did the trick!